# Access the common method from other component

Tags: html, angular, angular5

Here I am using some method for frequently used methods in common method ts file. If I am going to access these method I got null values  Please help me out.

**CommonMethod.ts:**

```
    GetCategoryList(){
        let Mylist = [];
        this.auth.Get("Master/Category").then((user) => {
          Mylist= user.json();
        });
        return Mylist;
      }
```

**My Another component:**

I am trying to access common method ts file here. by below way.

```
    import {CommonMethod} from './CommonMethod';
    ...
    ...
    construtor(private com:CommonMethod){}
    ngOninit(){
         console.log(this.com.GetCategoryList());
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked , if the function is returning anything or not, inside the function body itself.

Answer (score 1):

`this.auth.Get` is going to be `async` in nature due to which the `return MyList` line will get called even before the callback to the `then` method is called and the data is arrived and set in `MyList`.

You can use the `async` `await` syntax to fix it:

```
async GetCategoryList() {
  let Mylist = [];
  const user = await this.auth.Get("Master/Category");
  Mylist = user.json();
  return Mylist;
}
```

You can then use it like this in your Component:

```
import {CommonMethod} from './CommonMethod';

...
...

construtor(private com: CommonMethod) {}

async ngOninit() {
  const myList = await this.com.GetCategoryList();
  console.log(myList);
}
```

**PS:** Make sure that `CommonMethod` is a service and is added to the `providers` array of your `@NgModule`

Answer (score 0):

Should update your common method:

```
GetCategoryList(): Promise<any>{
        let Mylist = [];
        return this.auth.Get("Master/Category").then((user) => {
          Mylist= user.json();
          Promise.resolve(Mylist);
        });

      }
```

And

```
ngOninit(){
        this.com.GetCategoryList().then(results=>{
            console.log(results);
        });

   }
```